# Bitrix как в компоненте Каталог настроить ЧПУ для подразделов?

Tags: битрикс

Добрый вечер, подскажите как настроить ЧПУ, есть Инфоблок каталог, в нем разделы электрика, сантехника.... в сантехнике есть разделы водоснабжение, канализация. Если ЧПУ выключено, то все работает отлично, передается такая ссылка: ?SECTION_ID=1 , тоесть все нормально, а когда включаю ЧПУ не работает, настройки ЧПУ такие:
в Инфоблоке:

## SITE_DIR#/kategory/

## SITE_DIR#/kategory/#SECTION_CODE_PATH#/

## SITE_DIR#/kategory/#SECTION_CODE_PATH#/#ELEMENT_CODE#/

на странице:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Проблема заключается в том, что для битрикса не очевидно как с такими настройками распознать подобрать подходящий шаблон.

```
/kategory/some_one/15/
```

В данном примере "15" это код секции или id продукта?

Попробуйте для элемента каталога использовать либо короткий адрес `product/#ELEMENT_CODE#/`, либо внесите отличие в шаблон адреса элемента. Например, `#SECTION_CODE_PATH#/product_#ELEMENT_CODE#/`